# Compile dotnet core 1.0 razor view on app start

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I've just found out that in aspnet core 1.0 I cannot compile razor views while publishing an app.
Can I invoke something in runtime on startup to init views' compilation? 
Upgrading to dotnet core 1.1 is out of question for now.

The reason why I want to compile views is that the first call to the action waits around 5 seconds for the view to show already after the action has passed the return statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a process that requests each page from your website.  As the page is requested the view will be compiled and the compiled version will be cached for the next time the page is requested.  This approach warms up the site so that it's hot and ready to go when a real visitor requests a page.